# How to Get Data using Mongoose when Multilingual is stored in collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have saved data in mongo db like

```
{
     "title": {
                "ar": "arabic name",
                "en": "english name"

            },
     "description": {
                "ar": "ar-description",
                "en": "arabic description"
            },
     "subCategories": [{ 
               "title": {
                    "ar": "arabic name",
                    "en": "english name"
            }],
 }
```

**Expected OutPut**:

```
    {
     "title": "arabic name",
     "description": "arabic description",
     "subCategories": [{"title": "arabic name"}],
    }
```

How can i query to mongoose to give this result on basis of language(en,ar). i am using mongoose, nodejs and express.
if cant with mongoose then any other solution ?
Thank you :)

Comment: instead of saving data like this, why dont you format the data in an easier format .divide the data as a whole into en and arabic. something like : { 'en': [{'title':'english name' ,...}, {..}] ,'arabic': [{'title':'arabic name' ,...}, {..}]  }

Comment: @ShoyebMemon then how can i query for get data if i save data in according to your method ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do would be storing an `unwinded` document

```
{
 "title": {
            "ar": "arabic name",
            "en": "english name"

        },
 "description": {
            "ar": "ar-description",
            "en": "arabic description"
        },
 "subCategories": [{ 
           "title": {
                "ar": "arabic name",
                "en": "english name"
        }],
 }
```

will become

```
// ar doc
{
 "lang": "ar",
 "title": "Arabic name",
 "description": "ar-description",
 "subCategories": [{ 
           "title": "arabic name"
        }],
 }
 // en doc
 {
 "lang": "en",
 "title": "English name",
 "description": "en-description",
 "subCategories": [{ 
           "title": "english name"
        }],
 }
```

In order to find an ar doc

```
Model.find({lang:'ar'})
```

would give you the expected result.